# Import large excel file using laravel excel and laravel queue

Tags: excel, laravel

**laravel excel version 3.1**
**laravel version 5.6**
i have over 100000 rows of data in excel file. I would like to import this data into my database.

**In My controller.php**

```
if(request()->file('fertilizer_import')) {
    $import = new FertilizerImport();
    $file = request()->file('fertilizer_import');
    dispatch(new FertilizerImportJob($import, $file));
}
```

**In my FertilizerImportJob.php**

```
public function __construct($import, $file)
{
    $this->import = $import;
    $this->file = $file;
}
public function handle()
{
    Excel::import($this->import, $this->file);
}
```

And then, I uploaded my excel file. It is enter one row in jobs table. I run `php artisan make:queue` but data is not enter my fertilizer table.
How can i do that? Please advice me.

Comment: Your parameters to the job looks like it's in the wrong order - is it supposed to be like that? You're passing `$file` first, but expecting `$file` to be the second parameter in the constructor?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I update my code.

Comment: What queue driver are you using?

Comment: @DelenaMalan i used `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`.

Answer (score 2):

You should Try to use chunk and queue in laravel/Maatwebsite
In controller file

```
public function importExcel()
    {
        $path = resource_path() . "/Houten.xlsx";
        \Excel::import(new TestImport, $path);
        return redirect('/')->with('success', 'All good!');
    return back();
    }
```

And in Your Import File app/Imports/testImports.php

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;

class TestImport implements ToCollection, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue,WithStartRow
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        //do your insertion here. //no seprate job required
    }

     public function startRow(): int 
    {
         return 1;
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

Then set QUEUE_DRIVER=database and run the code. You will see one entry in jobs table. then you need to run this job. there are multiple ways to run any job. below is one
In your terminal

```
php artisan queue:restart
php artisan queue:listen
```

this will execute the code in collection function in chunks and will insert your data.

Comment: That work very well, but according to [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/batch-inserts.html) batchSize is related to ToModel concern, which is not the case for ToCollection plus WithChunkReading traits. At last, WithStartRow makes possible to start from a specific row, which is useful during development process, but in this example is not explicit necessary.

Comment: Thank you! Was looking for that. Works perfect.

Comment: Glad It helped.